# Problems with VB Notify Icon

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0, notifyicon

Okay I know this may sound like a newb question, but I am banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why this code won't work.

```
NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(5000, "title", "text", ToolTipIcon.Info)
```

That code should show a balloon notification from an icon in the system tray right? It will show my icon in the system tray but it will not show the balloon tip for some reason. I have used the notify icon in the past but for some reason it is not working.

I am using Visual Basic 2012 with **.NET Framework 4 Client Profile** as the target framework any ideas on why this is not working would be greatly appreciated.

I have already checked my registry and it is set to show balloon tips too so I really have no idea now.

Comment: There's a global system setting that disables *all* notification balloon tips.  You probably have it turned on and forgot about it.  [More here](http://www.windowsreference.com/general/how-to-enabledisable-tooltips-in-windows/).

Comment: I looked and my show balloon tip was set to 1, so I still have no idea what is going on here.

Comment: Does the debugger actually step into that line of code?  If so, do you have the Icon property assigned and the Visible property set to true?

Comment: Yes I have the icon property assigned the visible property to true. The debugger does also step into that line of code and it doesn't give any problems. I actually just tried running the program on a different computer and it worked fine, so it seems like it is a problem with my particular computer setup, and not the code itself.

Comment: @HansPassant - That link seems to refer to tool tips.  According to [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307729) a different registry setting controls balloon tips.